# Renderscript: 3D lookup table to convert an RGB triplet to a byte value

Tags: android, renderscript

I load a 3D lookup map which associates triplets of RGB byte values, to a single byt value. I define my allocation like this:

```
    Type.Builder tbLookup = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs));
    tbLookup.setX(256);
    tbLookup.setY(256);
    tbLookup.setZ(256);
    tbLookup.setMipmaps(false);
    tbLookup.setFaces(false);

    lookup  = Allocation.createTyped(rs, tbLookup.create(), Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE,  Allocation.USAGE_GRAPHICS_CONSTANTS);
    int ncolors = 256*256*256; 
    byte[] sampledata = new byte[ncolors];
    lookup.copyFrom(sampledata);
    script.set_gLookup(lookup); //global variable gLookup in renderscript
```

Then I define my kernel in renderscript:

```
rs_allocation gLookup;

uchar4 __attribute__((kernel)) lookItUp(const uchar4 in, uint32_t x, uint32_t y)
{
      uchar4 out = in;
      uchar p = rsGetElementAt_uchar(gLookup, in.r,in.g,in.b);
      out.r = p;
      out.g = p;
      out.b = p;
      return out;
}
```

This doesn't work, it outputs zero values (black image) and works extremely slow. If I don't do the `rsGetElementAt_uchar`, then it works fast (I can assign a fixed value and it's okay). So I must be doing something wrong with the lookup table type. Any clue?
Thank you!

P.S: A 3d lookup table is not a crazy idea, there already is an Intrinsic function for converting RGB to RGBA by using a 3D lookup table. But I need my own lookup table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that should be USAGE_SCRIPT--I don't know what USAGE_GRAPHICS_CONSTANT will do there, but it's definitely not what you want.

Comment: I thought I had already tried with USAGE_SCRIPT. The thing is, now the above code does work. Thank you!